# Should I have a visa to enter Turkey to get my luggage?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, turkey, greece

I'm travelling from Doha to Cairo on two flight with two confirmations numbers. The website which I booked from has made my trip on two flights and sent me two emails with two confirmation numbers (I've booked whole trip via opodo.com).

The first flight is from Doha (Qatar) to Istanbul (Turkey) on Qatar Airways. Then I shall wait 3 hours and then go to another trip from Istanbul to Athene and then clearly a transit (written in confirmation email) from Athena To Cairo on Aegean airlines.

My question is: Do I have to require a visa just to get my luggage from the first flight and check-in with the other airline? Or shall the luggage be moved from the flights by asking Qatar Airways to move them to the other flight and what should I do to just check in online with the other airline?

Notes :

1. I hold the Egyptian normal passport.
2. I will arrive to Istanbul on terminal 1 and departure from the same terminal so I will not have to exit the arrival terminal to catch the other trip which is not a transit trip It's a new one to Greece.

Comment: Try contacting Qatar's customer service, give them your confirmation number and _ask them_ whether your booking is one where your luggage will be checked through to Cairo.

Comment: With hybrid or [hacker itineraries/fares](https://www.kayak.com/news/hacker-fare/) where there are two different confirmation numbers, it is usually (maybe always) the case that your luggage is not transferred. The chances are slim to none that Qatar Airways will undertake the logistics of moving the bags to your onward flight on Aegean. You will need new luggage tags from Aegean